# QXmlSchema failing to validate and giving odd console output

Tags: c++, xml, qt, validation, xsd

**Edit**
I have added a minumum working code sample that produces the same errors at the bottom...

I have an xsd schema file and an xml file, both of which I have validated online, and I have used online tools to validate the xml file using my xsd schema. Everything is valid and compatible. I am now trying to use QXmlSchemaValidator to validate the same xml, using the same xsd, however, when I call:

```
if (!validator.validate(file.fileName()))
```

it returns false.

Here is the code snippet in which this happens:

```
LoadInfo JobTreeControl::loadXML_schemaValidation(QFile& file, QXmlStreamReader& iXml)
{
    QString schemeFilePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/schema.xsd";
    QFile schemaFile(schemeFilePath);

    if (!schemaFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        return LoadInfo(false, "Schema file failed to open");

    QXmlSchema schema;

    if (!schema.load( QUrl::fromLocalFile(schemeFilePath)))
        return LoadInfo(false, "Qt schema failed to load schema file");

    if (!schema.isValid())
        return LoadInfo(false, "Schema is invalid");

    QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);

    if (!validator.validate(file.fileName()))
        return LoadInfo(false, "Load file is not a valid Pointfuse Batch Utility XML file");

    return LoadInfo(true);
}
```

I also get some interesting console output from the schema and validator:

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::aboutToQuit() to
>   QNativeWifiEngine::closeHandle() QEventLoop: Cannot be used without
>   QApplication QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication Error
>   FODC0002 in c:/test Data/serializeArchive/test_newSaveFormat.xml, at
>   line 1, column 0: Premature end of document.

I have tried googling these errors and QXmlSchema issues, and I'm not having much luck turning up anything. I did find this post which is close:

[QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697107/qeventloop-cannot-be-used-without-qapplication)

...but his issue was that he didn't have an instance of QApplication running and therefor no event loop. I can tell you for certain that I do, as this code snippet is very deep inside my application, and is accessed when clicking on a QAction and having a QDialog pop up.

Below I'll write out which lines of code cause which console outputs:

```
QXmlSchema schema;
```

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::aboutToQuit() to
>   QNativeWifiEngine::closeHandle()

```
    if (!schema.load( QUrl::fromLocalFile(schemeFilePath)))
```

> QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication

```
    if (!validator.validate(file.fileName()))
```

> QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication Error FODC0002 in
>   c:/test Data/serializeArchive/test_newSaveFormat.xml, at line 1,
>   column 0: Premature end of document.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give,

Pete

**Edit:**

I can also confirm that both the xml filepath use to load QFile file, and the schemaFilePath used to load QFile schemaFile, are correct. Though this is confirmed when I successfully open and load each of these files.

**Edit**

And I'm curious to know why on earth my QXmlSchema is calling functions relating to QNativeWifiEngine... What does that have to do with the schema?

**Edit With Minimum Working Example Code**

I have written the shortest working example I can think of.

Bellow is the c++/Qt source:

```
class XmlValidator : public QDialog
{

public:

    XmlValidator()
        : QDialog()
    {
        QVBoxLayout* p_vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        QPushButton* p_pushButton = new QPushButton("Validate XML");

        p_vBoxLayout->addWidget(p_pushButton);
        this->setLayout(p_vBoxLayout);

        connect(p_pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &XmlValidator::validateXML);
    }

    void validateXML(); 
};

void XmlValidator::validateXML()
{
    QString xmlFilePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/testXml.xml";
    QString schemeFilePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/testSchema.xsd";

    QFile xmlFile(xmlFilePath);
    QFile schemaFile(schemeFilePath);

    if (!xmlFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        std::cout << "Xml file failed to open" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!schemaFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        std::cout << "Schema file failed to open" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    QXmlSchema schema;

    if (!schema.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(schemeFilePath)))
    {
        std::cout << "Qt schema failed to load schema file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!schema.isValid())
    {
        std::cout << "Schema is invalid" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);

    if (!validator.validate(xmlFilePath))
    {
        std::cout << "Xml file is not a valid" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    XmlValidator dialog;

    dialog.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Then testXml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testSchemaElement version="4.5"/>
```

And finally testSchema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="testSchemaElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The c++ application will look for these two files in it's working directory.

Comment: The SO article you mentoined has a comment **a QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);** would be sufficient. Did you tried this (create instance without using the exec() function). Not very beautiful, but may help..

Comment: QApplication a(argc, argv); is the very first line of my main function, unless you're suggesting I add another instance elsewhere?

Comment: @IronAttorney Don't add a second, one is enough. Maybe `loadXML_schemaValidation()` is executed before `main()` ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. Everything that happens in my app starts in main. As I said, I am triggering this function from a QDialog that I opened by clicking on a QAction in my GUI, all of which utilized signals and slots to make this work. I'm trying to make a small compilable test case, but however I slice it, I need to make a user interface to trigger the Xml schema functions, otherwise I can't call exec on QApplication AND use the schema, haha

Comment: If I remember well, QXmlSchema  uses network functionality to access the files (the fact that it uses QUrl is an hint). Also, why do you open `schemaFile`? You do not need to, you just need to pass the path to QUrl.

Comment: I read that you have to open it with at least the QFile::ReadOnly option in order to use it with the schema.

And thanks for pointing out the QUrl business, that does make more sense

Comment: I've nearly finished the minimum compilable example, I'll post it up as an edit when I have...

Comment: sorry, got to bump this