# Use Qts QXmlSchemaValidator without QApplication

Tags: c++, qt

I need some help in Qt since I don't really undestand the way Qt libraries can be used in visual studio projects. I try to use the QXmlSchemaValidator class from QtXmlPatterns to validate an xml file against schema, but I can't  instantiate a QApplication object since I don't have access to the main.cpp file. I don't want to create a Qt project, just try to use this schemaValidator class in one of a class' method.
This is how I try to load the schema:

```
QUrl url("http://.../schema.xsd");

QXmlSchema schema;
    if (schema.load(url))
        qDebug() << "schema is valid";
    else
    qDebug() << "schema is invalid";
```

I get this warning: *"Please instantiate the QApplication object first"*.

I found a solution here: [QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697107/qeventloop-cannot-be-used-without-qapplication) that says I need the main function to look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Is there a way to load the schema and validate my xml files without a QApplication object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `QCoreApplication` instead.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //your code here

    return a.exec();
}
```

Seriously, if some Qt features you like require an event loop, you just can't get away with it without one. About not having a "Qt project" (and maybe you mean you're not using `qmake`) but yet using Qt classes: good luck.