# QEventloop canot be used without QApplication

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I'm currently developing a Console Unit Test Client with Google Test.
The Tests involves a step where a binary file is downloaded from a server.
To download this file I thought about using Qt.

Now I took the example code from
https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL

This gives me the error `QEventloop canot be used without QApplication`

I found this thread [QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697107/qeventloop-cannot-be-used-without-qapplication)

However this works for a UI application.
My googletest main is predefined

```
GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  printf("Running main() from %s\n", __FILE__);
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Where would be a good place to add the QApplication?

Could you help me out?

thx for your help :)

Comment: Place it in int main() just like any other Qt application

Comment: so like this?
```GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
QApplication a(argc, argv);
testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();}
```

Comment: I believe that is correct.